# didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) did not work if i move the body quickly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two objects in the scene and the user can move them when the contact begins I change the color of the selected object, and when the contract ends the color is changed also, the problem is when I move the object quickly the method `didEnd` do not work. It works just when I move the object slowly, I have no problem with `didBegin`.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You are using fingers and manually moving the objects?  You are pretending to be god and not using the physics world in the proper way.  This is not a situation where you should be using the physics engine.

Comment: Then how can i detect if two objects are collided or not ?

Comment: Manually check if the two frames intersect, or use the physics engine to move your sprite